# Keyboard shortcut to automatically wrap selected text in IsNull([text], 0) in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, isnull

Is there some way to have a shortcut in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) that when text is selected, it wraps that text in an IsNull() statement?

For example, I highlight the text below:

```
My_column_name
```

and when I click the keyboard shortcut, what was highlighted turns into:

```
IsNull(My_column_name, 0)
```

I am using SSMS v17.4

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to do this with native SSMS. There may be this functionality in some third party extensions but I don't know of any. That is a pretty specific rule. If you have intellisense enabled it isn't much more to type it then some custom shortcut key combo you could devise.

Comment: If you have something like SQL Prompt you could set up a snippet to do this, but this isn't something native to SSMS.

Comment: Although there is nothing native, there are a number of alternative suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647594/macros-in-sql-server-management-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this done using snippets. It's not exactly a simple shortcut, but a few keystrokes will get you there.

First you need to create a snippet like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>ISNULL</Title>
            <Shortcut></Shortcut>
            <Description>Inserts ISNULL function</Description>
            <Author>Luis Cazares</Author>
            <SnippetTypes>
                <SnippetType>SurroundsWith</SnippetType>
            </SnippetTypes>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
        </Declarations>
        <Code Language="SQL"><![CDATA[ISNULL( $end$$selected$, 0)]]>
        </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Save this as a `.snippet` file and save it on a folder destined for snippets. You could use the one set as default. To know which folder is your default or to add a different folder, go to the `Code Snippets Manager` in the Tools menu for SSMS.

Once your snippet is on a registered location, select the code, press `Ctrl+K,Ctrl+S` and the snippets context menu will appear. You can traverse it by starting typing the folder and snippet name and pressing Enter or Right when getting there.

It's probably not worth it for short snippets, but for larger ones it's amazing. I wrote a more detailed explanation [in here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/using-code-snippets-in-ssms).

Answer (score 3):

I may have found a way. In the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SQL\Snippets\1033\Function` directory (adjust accordingly for your installation), I copied the `Begin End.snippet` file, named the copy `IsNull.snippet`, and modified the new file. I changed:

```
BEGIN

$selected$ $end$

END
```

To:

```
IsNull($selected$ $end$, 0)
```

(I also changed the Title, Description, and Author tags -- do whatever you want with those.)

Then, in SSMS, I used `Tools -> Code Snippets Manager` to import the new snippet. Now, with `My_column_name` selected in a query window, I can use Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S, Down, Down, Enter, Down, Enter to apply the new snippet.

It's not a single keystroke, but it's heading in that direction. Maybe this will inspire someone else who can make it even better.

Comment: It's funny how we posted an answer on the same topic almost at the same time. Same solution, but explained in a different way.