# Keyboard shortcut to automatically wrap selected text in IsNull([text], 0) in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, isnull, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there some way to have a shortcut in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) that when text is selected, it wraps that text in an IsNull() statement?

For example, I highlight the text below:

```
My_column_name
```

and when I click the keyboard shortcut, what was highlighted turns into:

```
IsNull(My_column_name, 0)
```

I type an IsNull after writing out the column name probably a dozen times a day, and when I'm in the thick of writing, this would be so handy!

Same question posted in StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604882/keyboard-shortcut-to-automatically-wrap-selected-text-in-isnulltext-0-in-ss

I am using SSMS v17.4